# How to edit Query in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a repository and I need to find data with id and date.

I write this code:

```
@Query(value = "select * from cheer.coordinate where childid = ?1 and CAST(creationdate as DATE) = ?2",
nativeQuery = true)
List<Coordinate> findAllByChildidAndDate(@Param("childid") Long childid, @Param("date") String date);
```

But when I try to use it I get this error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = character varying

How to fix it?

Comment: example which works in postgres console: `select * from cheer.coordinate where childid = 1 and CAST(creationdate as DATE) = '30-01-2020';`

Comment: Don't pass dates as strings, pass them as instances of `LocalDate`, so `@Param("date") LocalDate date)`